# How can I add --add-exports to a gradle application?

Tags: gradle, javafx, gradle-kotlin-dsl, java-module

I'm working on a Java 11 application that uses the java module system. I need to use reflection to access an internal function of the JavaFX library. The java module containing that function doesn't export it, so I get the following error when I run the gradle build task:

```
import com.sun.javafx.tk.TKStage;
                     ^
  (package com.sun.javafx.tk is declared in module javafx.graphics, which does not export it to module com.sampleapp)
```

I believe that means I need to do `--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=com.sampleapp`, however, I'm not sure how to do this in gradle. I've tried adding it to the `applicationDefaultJvmArgs`, which didn't work.

```
application {
    ...

    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf(
        "--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=com.sampleapp"
    )
}
```

I've also tried adding it to `gradle.properties.kts` and it didn't work.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs = listOf(
    "--add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=com.sampleapp"
)
```

Comment: Your second approach doesn't work because it sets the JVM arguments for the Gradle daemon, not your application. Your first approach will work, but for the `run` task (and probably will affect the scripts created by the `distribution` plugin). As you've discovered, the error you're seeing is a compilation error and so you need to configure the compilation tasks (e.g. `compileJava`).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the issue by adding:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.compilerArgs.addAll(arrayOf(
        "--add-exports", "javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=com.sampleapp"
    ))
}
```